# Can a curse, jinx or spell be fought off or resisted?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

We know that curses such as the Imperius curse can be fought off (or resisted) internally.

Can other curses or even jinxes (such as the Impedimenta jinx) be fought off?

I'm thinking mainly of the Tarantallegra curse which Neville suffered twice. Or Legilimency being resisted by Occlumency.

**Edit:**
I should have mentioned that I mean *after* one has been struck by the curse. Lets leave out shields and deflections.

Similar to when Harry fought off the Imperius curse twice. This is after he had been struck by it.

So, **could someone resist the effects of a curse, jinx or spell once they had been hit by it?**

Comment: What is Talantalagra curse?

Comment: Sorry about the spelling, the one which makes the victim's legs dance about uncontrollably.

Comment: It's worth noting that both Imperius and Legilimency are "mind control spells" and so it makes sense for them to be more resistable by mental effort than Stunning or other more physical spells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally no.  Curses and jinxes seem to fit one of three categories:

1. Permanent until removed (Leg-locker, fully body bind, acne curse from book 5, etc) or with durations measured in hours or days.  Notably, Harry was hit by this in Book 6, covered with his Cloak, and left on the train.  We don't see how long it would have taken to fade or be fought off, as Harry was rescued by Tonks.  Notably in the earlier books, Neville was hit by several of these which lasted for hours each.
2. Based on concentration of caster (most jinxes, like Quirrel's broom-disrupting jinx from Book 1).  In fact, the [Harry Potter wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Spell) indicates that jinxes *always* last only so long as eye contact is maintained.
3. Continual, but eventually resistible (*Imperius*).

It seems that all of these types of spells lift upon the death of the caster.  The only one known that can be fought off after it has hit is the Imperius curse, which leaves the victim fully mobile, fully aware, and still capable of doing magic.  It's likely that this is the reason it can eventually be fought off.

Comment: This most closely answers my question.

Answer (score 5):

Protego blocks a spell. I imagine it would block Tarantellegra. Not all spells can be blocked, for example Avada Kedavra. Some spells, such as the Imperius Curse, can be fought off by sheer willpower -- the ability to do this will vary wizard to wizard, depending on the wizard's skill, powers, and magical ability. Pretty basic answer.

**ETA:** Oops, sorry I repeated the bit about the Imperius Curse that you mentioned in the question1

Comment: Good answer. How about once the curse has been hit?

Comment: Not entirely correct, as you can read, "The only known counter-spell is sacrificial protection", means, the Avada Kedavra curse can be blocked too: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Killing_Curse

Answer (score 3):

Once hit there are counter spells for some. which is why they have healers.. But not everything is fixable. Some spells are temporary and can be waited out till the effects disappear. Like the curse Ron hit himself with where he started regurgitating slugs..But curses with permanent effects like avada kedavra are not undoable. Some can be fought off even after hit, which also includes the Imperius curse. But it depends on how long the curse is used or on the wizard's willpower to hold on

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes yes.  Hagrid resists the stunning spells sent to him in *Order of the Phoenix*.  I don't understand how he did that.

Comment: Simon: unless you can find a canon source, that's just something invented on the Harry Potter Wikia, repeated in http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51203/4918 .  It's also totally contrary to what I'd expect.  We learn in *Order of the Phoenix* that giants are not magic users, in fact they *hate* magic, so I think giants should have no or almost no magic resistance.

Comment: Is it possible though that as a half-giant, Hagrid has a very high Constitution score, and has made his saves against the stun spells?

Comment: @Simon: nice quote.  I still don't think he's resistant to magic though, instead I take that to mean Hagrid has just made his fortitude saves because of a racial bonus to his constitution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some spells such as the full body-bind curse "Pectrificus totalus" are maintained even subconsciously by the caster. When Dumbledore was killed by Snape, Harry was released. 
It raises the issue of spell effects duration charms, transfiguartion.. we know for instance that there is a permanenet Sticking charm Walburga Black used on her painting, thought it may be more of a curse  than a charm to the extent that curses are designed not to wear off or to inflict long lasting pain or damages (eg Sectum Sempra).I think we all agree Walburga's painting **WAS** a pain in the erm... bottom (sigh,they could've cut the call around the painting).